# 439 activex component can't create object error on launching a PDF file in VB6

Tags: vb6, activexobject

I installed my VB6 application on a 64 bit Windows 7 machine and I'm getting following error message when I click on a file to launch the PDF file.

> 439 activex component can't create object

When I debugged I see the error came on the following line

```
createobject( oracleinprocserver.xorasession )
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I need to install `Oracle objects for OLE`

[this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5d424996-e3f3-4b18-a1ad-f18f1b6937ef/runtime-error-429-activex-component-cant-create-object?forum=vbgeneral) helped me resolve the issue.